# How can i view environment variables of pivotal cloud foundry app while running the app on localhost

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I used to view all the environment variables(defined in application.properties) of traditional springboot app by going to http://localhost:8080/env.  Now, i am running the app on pivotal cloud foundry environment and trying to hit the : http://localhost:8080/env but is not working for me for pivotal cloud foundry set up.

**Note**: i know how to view the environment variables from CF CLI or APP Manager. But i dont want to do it that way. I am trying to fetch them through localhost:8080 link only.

Comment: What is the response you're getting when you hit http://localhost:8080/env

Comment: White label error page "There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)."

Comment: Do you have profile specific `management` properties which runs fine for local profile but not for PCF?

Comment: It doesn't sound related to Cloud Foundry. Your app is just returning a 404 ("white label error" is a Spring Boot message). The only difference that comes to mind for deploying to CF is that Spring will automatically enable the "cloud" profile, which might change the way that Spring Boot Actuator is set up (I believe you're referring to an actuator endpoint with `/env`). You could try enabling the `cloud` profile when you run locally and see if that has any impact. Also, check the route mapped to your app and see if there is a path associated with that route. That could cause issues too.

Comment: Also, just double check this https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-enabling-endpoints

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use the config server for this which basically gets the application.properties from a git repository.
Please find the references here.
https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/1-5/common/config-server/index.html

The second option will be to get it as a static file and like a js or CSS file the references for this option can be found here.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources

Answer (score 1):

Use Spring-Actuator to enable such functionality https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html